# Entity framework On Delete Cascade

Tags: sql-server, entity

I have a one to one relation set up like this

```
           modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
                    .HasOptional(d => d.Contact)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(key => key.ContactID);
```

Contact is an optional field for subject, however if I try to delete a contact still being referenced by a subject, it gives me a foreign key constraint error. If I add .WillCascadeOnDelete. Then deleting a contact also deletes the subject.

Is there anyway to do what im trying to do with a one-to-one FK relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as it should be.
You can't delete a parent that is being referenced by a child.

As a best practice, try adding an `Status` column to your table and show only those with `Status` set to `true`, and when you want to delete something, just set the `Status` to false by changing one line in your delete action from:

```
db.yourentity.Remove(yourentityinstance);
```

To:

```
yourentityinstance.Status = false;
```